# Lazy calculation for Class

Tags: python, idioms

I want to be able to perform operations on instances of a class, but delay the actual calculation unitl another class calls for them to run.

My below (simplified) code works. Instances of `Foo` (here: `f3` and `f4`) are only calculated once I call `run()` on `FooStorage` which stores all instances of Foo.

**Question: Is there a way to achieve this with a build-in mechanism such as a decorator on the `__add__` method?**

```
import operator as op

MathOps = {"+":op.add, "*": op.mul} 

class FooStorage():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo_list = []

    def add_to_foolist(self,foo):
        self.foo_list.append(foo)

    def run(self):
        for f in self.foo_list:
            f._calc()

class Foo():
    def __init__(self,storage, values=None, op=None):
        self._foostorage = storage
        self.values = values
        storage.add_to_foolist(self)
        self.op = op


    def __add__(self,other):
        op = ("+",self,other)
        return Foo(self._foostorage, op=op)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        pass
        # to come

    def _calc(self):
        if self.op:
            op, left, right = self.op
            self.values = MathOps[op](left.values,right.values)


fs = FooStorage()
f1 = Foo(fs, values=1)
f2 = Foo(fs,values=2)
f3 = f1 + f2 # update f3 value only once fs.run() is called
f4 = f3 + f1 # update f4 value only once fs.run() is called

fs.run() # triggers calculation
f4.values
```

Comment: Delay it in what sense (until when)? There are ways of lazily creating class attributes, but it's unclear whether that would apply here (broadly speaking, partially because classes generally shouldn't be aware of their instances).

Comment: I want to delay calculation until I call run from the other class. However, I am unsure If my approach can be improved by some pythonic way

Comment: what would the value of `f3` be before `fs.run` is called?

Comment: Just move the `fs.run()` so it's before where `f3` and `f4` are calculated.

Comment: @amdex it should be None. Basically I just want to delay lengthy calculations to the end and make some additional sanity checks before hand

Comment: @martineau I didn't make my point clear. The above code is able to achieve what I want. However, I am wondering if there is a better way of achieving this.